# Анализ предложения с точки зрения смысла

Tags: фразеология

В ходе ввода прибора учета в эксплуатацию проверке подлежат:
б) соответствие прибора учета технической документации изготовителя прибора, в том числе комплектации и схеме монтажа прибора учета;

Смысл пункта б) я трактую следующим образом:
В первой части предложения говорится о необходимости провести некие действия, целью которых является установление факта соответствия прибора учета критериям изложенным в технической документации изготовителя прибора. Следующий после запятой союз "в том числе" является присоединением уточнения тех действий, о которых сказано в первой части предложения. Иными словами нужно проверить соответствие прибора учета комплектации и схемы монтажа указанных в технической документации изготовителя прибора.

Или речь идет о схеме монтажа, которая должна быть составлена кем угодно?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Речь идёт о том, что перед началом эксплуатации прибор должен быть укомплектован в соответствии с документацией и смонтирован (подключён) у потребителя по *схеме, имеющейся в документации*, составленной изготовителем. Выражение "в том числе" применено не совсем удачно (с ним бывает и гораздо хуже - это одна из болезней разговорного языка последних лет), здесь уместнее "*в частности*". Либо (если оставлять "в том числе"), можно добавить слово "требованиям" (документации) - тогда это будет присоединением уточнения (общее понятие "требований" документации конкретизируется частностями: "в числе" *требований* упомянуты требование комплектности оборудования и требование соответствия схеме подключения).

Answer (score 1):

> Иными словами нужно проверить соответствие прибора учета комплектации
>   и схемы монтажа указанных в технической документации изготовителя
>   прибора.

Я отказываюсь это понимать. Что такое "прибор учета комплектации и схемы"?

Совет: никогда не пытайтесь выразить на русском языке мысль подобным образом. Обычно непонимание возникает уже после двух вложенных или рядом стоящих родительных падежей. У вас - четыре, если не пять:  *соответствие прибора(1) учета(2) комплектации(3) и схемы(4) монтажа(5)*.

Справедливости ради: автор инструкции тоже не промах по этой части канцелярита: *соответствие прибора(1) учета(2) технической документации(3) изготовителя(4) прибора(5)*, - те же пять родительных - но здесь хоть понятно, что к чему, потому что (3) - на самом деле дательный. Это терпимо.

Что же до текста, вызвавшего вопросы, то он пусть и отдает канцеляритом, но в общем понятен.

В ходе ввода прибора (какого?) учета в эксплуатацию проверке подлежат (что?)...

... (что?) соответствие (чего? чему?)...

...[соответвие] (чего?) прибора учета...

...[соответвие] (чему?) технической документации (чьей, какой?) изготовителя прибора,...

... в том числе (чему?) комплектации и (чему?) схеме монтажа прибора учета;

---

По-другому здесь понять трудно.

Другими словами, устанавливается, что ***прибор соответствует документации изготовителя, составными частями которой являются некие "комплектация" и "схема монтажа" (под которыми понимаются разделы или части "документации")***.

---

Что до ваших предположений, то я просто не смог понять, что вы попытались сформулировать. Откуда там может взяться "схема, составленная кем угодно"  - это вообще загадка. Но и первое предположение не намного лучше:

> Иными словами нужно проверить соответствие прибора учета комплектации
>   и схемы монтажа указанных в технической документации изготовителя
>   прибора.

Не знаю, о чем тут говориться, но в любом случае проверяется соответствие *прибора - **схеме***. А не "прибора схемы".

Comment: "соответствие прибора - схеме" это понятно, не понятно где схема должна быть: в составе технической документации изготовителя прибора или где-то еще?

Comment: @Tester500 Ну знаете, там же в "том числе" есть. Если вам напишут что-то типа "В автобусе запрещено нарушать общественные нормы, в том числе плевать на пол", у вас не возникнет вопроса, пол - это в автобусе или еще где? В документации конечно. Да и без "того числа" трудно даже представить что-то иное.  ..

Comment: @ Tester500  Конечно же, схема должна быть в документации, и не только по практической логике. Выражение "в том числе" (при правильном употреблении, конечно) всегда связывает ранее упомянутое общее понятие с последующими частными, поэтому то, что идёт за ним - частный случай "соответствия документации".

Comment: Приведенный мной текст из постановления правительства РФ №354 параграф VII пункт 81(4). Управляющая компания трактует этот пункт так: представителю УК нужно сверить прибор с паспортом устройства, и сверх того со схемой монтажа, которую должен предоставить собственник жилья (ну т.е. тот кто установил прибор, должен еще и схему нарисовать). И вот с этой, нарисованной собственником схемой прибор и нужно сверить. Более того они требуют не просто схему, а целый проект. Причем рисование схемы и проекта предлагают сделать силами УК, за мзду ес-нно. У меня сейчас идет суд, УК зацепились за эту схему.

Comment: Я хочу предоставить в суде грамотно составленное толкование этого пункта. По полученным тут ответам я понял, моя версия толкования верна. Каюсь, в самом вопросе я неверно построил пример толкования, прошу в этом винить конец рабочего дня

Comment: @Tester500  *соответствие прибора учета технической документации изготовителя прибора,* - так это вы не по адресу. Вам надо лингвистическую экспертизу заказывать. Судам в общем-то все равно, что мы тут вам скажем, судебное толкование документов - не в нашей компетенции. Но в данном случае случае это, боюсь, будет пустым занятием. Для экспертизы нужно очень четко сформулировать вопрос для экспертного заключения. Да еще и на пустом месте проблема  раздута. Из-за толкования одного знака пересматривать смысл документа никто не будет. Не было прецедентов.